# How to perform multiple redirects in NGINX

Tags: nginx, webserver

I am making my first nginx configuration file. I have 2 goals:

1. redirect all non "www" requests to "www" version
2. redirect all traffic which used to be served in a subdirectory of an ip addressed folder

ie:

mysite.com >>> "www.mysite.com"

and

123.456.789.123/BETA >>> "www.mysite.com"

Here is my config:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name 123.456.789.123;
            return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
    }
    server {
            listen 80;
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name mysite.com;
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.mysite.com$1;
            location ~* ^/BETA/ {
                    return 301 /;
            }
    }
```

mysite.com >>> "www.mysite.com" works but
123.456.789.123/BETA >>> "www.mysite.com" is instead giving: "www.mysite.com/BETA"

It feels like I am doing something wrong here... Should there be 2 "server" blocks? If so how should I structure this to use one? Is "location" the right way to rewrite the subdirectory to the root? Is it maybe causing some conflict with the re-write in the same server block? Should I create a 3rd server block to rewrite the subdirectory to the root? Is there a way to **directly** rewrite 123.456.789.123/BETA to www.mysite.com ?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

This should do it, I modified your code to redirect 123.456.789.123/BETA to www.mysite.com (just remove the $request_uri for requests to 123.456.789.123/BETA). For any other pages requested of 123.456.789.123, such as 123.456.789.123/foo will redirect to www.mysite.com/foo.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 123.456.789.123;
        location = /BETA {
                return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com;
        }
        return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mysite.com;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.mysite.com$1;
}
```

If you want to redirect subpages of /BETA, such as /BETA/foo, to www.mysite.com as well, remove the '=' in that line before /BETA.

EDIT: Not sure if this was clear, but you'll need a third server block with server_name www.mysite.com that actually serves your website.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working - I still get:
123.456.789.123/BETA >>> www.mysite.com/BETA

Comment: Browsers store permanent redirect info. Try opening on a new device or check how to remove browsing data for your browser. For testing, I can also recommend using 302 redirects to make testing easier. For chrome: https://salferrarello.com/chrome-clear-redirect-cache/

Comment: Tried private browsing as well as a different and got the same

Comment: Ok, try removing the removing the $request_uri from the first server block entirely. That should definitely work and then we can back-track from there.

Comment: There is definitely some kind of caching going on because even when I remove all of the code, save the config file, and restart the service I get the same result. I'll see what is going on with that. Thanks for the education. If the code works after I resolve caching I will accept the answer

Comment: Woohoo!! works now. Thanks! And thanks for helping me understand nginx better by your comments and their implications!

Comment: Glad I could help :) The caching will get ya